# In Jenkins while executing some code its throwing an error "jq command not found"

Tags: jenkins, jq

Jenkins jq command not found in Windows

I tried executing curl command in Jenkins using Execute Shell in my local machine 
command that I tried,

```
access_token=$(echo "$auth_call" | jq '.Token' | tr -d '"' )
```

and while executing it, it throws an error,

```
++ jq .Token
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins7847423252232692785.sh: line 8: jq: command not found
++ tr -d '"'
+ access_token=
+ echo
```

Can you please tell me how to install the "`jq`" package for windows machine and how to set it up for the Jenkins to access that package.

```
access_token=$(echo "$auth_call" | jq '.Token' | tr -d '"' )
```

It shouldn't throw the error.

Comment: It's not that different from making any app accessible from the command line. Put jq on the path or in the current working directory or hardcode a path directly to it on that machine...

Comment: I tried that as well, It didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

> I tried that as well, It didn't work

First, make sure you have a jq.exe working, before trying to call it from a Jenkins job.
If not, download [`jq-1.6/jq-win64.exe`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-win64.exe) and rename it `jq.exe`.

Second, make sure your Jenkins will execute its job on itself (`master` node).

Third, try again with the full path of your `jq.exe` program, and see if the issue persists.